# What is new way of setting DateTimeSerializationOptions.Defaults in mongodb c# driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, datetime-format

I was using this line to set the datetime defaults.

```
DateTimeSerializationOptions.Defaults = DateTimeSerializationOptions.LocalInstance;
```

I get this warning.
**'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Options.DateTimeSerializationOptions.Defaults' is obsolete: 'Create and register a DateTimeSerializer with the desired options instead.**'

But i couldn't find an example to change it... how can I change this obsolute usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register the date/time serializer like this:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime), DateTimeSerializer.LocalInstance);
```

Note that you can't register a serializer once one has already been registered. Also, the driver creates a default serializer for each type the first time it needs one. So you need to call this code *before* you make your first call to the driver to read or write data.

Comment: BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime), DateTimeSerializer.LocalInstance);