# How to set BsonDateTime Serializer default options in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, bson, gridfs

I need to store `DateTime` in MongoDb with the same precission as in .NET `DateTime`. I found this solution:

```
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Representation = BsonType.Document)] 
public DateTime RequestedTime
```

... to use attributes and BsonDocument type to store also `Ticks` property of .NET DateTime.

The thing is

1. I don't want to do this for every DateTime
2. I don't want to have Mongo reference in my Domain.

I found this [post](https://alexmg.dev/posts/datetime-precision-with-mongodb-and-the-c-driver) and this [sof question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185262/what-is-new-way-of-setting-datetimeserializationoptions-defaults-in-mongodb-c-sh) which propose to use DateTimeSerializer as

```
    DateTimeSerializationOptions options = new DateTimeSerializationOptions(DateTimeKind.Utc, BsonType.Document); 
    var serializer = new DateTimeSerializer(options);
    BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime), serializer);
```

But the hell I'm not able to find out where should I do this. Startup? Program? Which package do I need to have access to `BsonDateTimeOptions` class as I cannot see it anywhere. Is it possible to set it outside of the assembly where affected properties are stored (aka drifting it away from Domain?)

I'm using GridFS Driver instead of classical mongo, is this the problem?